# C-x 4 b open a new buffer to the left of the current buffer

Tags: emacs

When strike `C-x 4 b` which invoke `ivy-switch-buffer-other-window`,

A new buffer will open vertically below the current.

How could position the newly-opened-buffer to the left of the current buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [code](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/83ba4bd3444c021b411116538fb75256b9f1a332/ivy.el#L472), `ivy-switch-buffer-other-window` is an enhanced version of the built-in `switch-to-buffer-other-window`. The latter command can be controlled with the variables `split-width-threshold` and `split-height-threshold` (link to [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Buffer-Display-Action-Functions)).

So to get Emacs to prefer to open new buffers side by side instead of below, you might try setting the variable `split-width-threshold` to a low number, like 50. This works for me on the non-ivy command, however, the new buffer opens on the right, not on the left.

See also [this involved stack exchange question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39034/prefer-vertical-splits-over-horizontal-ones) if you want finer control.